# Version of VideoView for Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an Android application. Сan I get the version of VideoView programmatically?
Maybe there's a way to find it using the firmware version?

Answer (score 0):

please try this code :

```
  try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("video player package name", 0);
        String version = pInfo.versionName;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```